# How to unit test permissions in django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

Hers is a sample permission that I want to unit test.

```
# permissions.py

from myapp.models import Membership

class IsOrganizationOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to allow only owner of the organization to do a certian task.
    """
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        try:
            membership = Membership.objects.get(user = request.user, organization = obj)
        except Membership.DoesNotExist:
            return False

        return membership.is_admin
```

and here is how it is applied

```
# viewsets.py
class OrganizationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows Organizations to be viewed or edited.
    """
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOrganizationOwner,)
    queryset = Organization.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = OrganizationSerializer
```

Now I am very new to testing in django and I don't know how to test this permission. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
from django_mock_queries.query import MockSet
from mock import patch, MagicMock
from unittest import TestCase


class TestPermissions(TestCase):
    memberships = MockSet()
    patch_memberships = patch('myapp.models.Membership.objects', memberships)

    def setUp(self):
        self.permission = IsOrganizationOwner()

        self.memberships.clear()
        self.request = MagicMock(user=MagicMock())
        self.view = MagicMock()

    def create_membership(self, organization, is_admin):
        self.request.user.is_admin = is_admin
        self.memberships.add(
            MagicMock(user=self.request.user, organization=organization)
        )

    @patch_memberships
    def test_permissions_is_organization_owner_returns_false_when_membership_does_not_exist(self):
        org = MagicMock()
        self.assertFalse(self.permission.has_object_permission(self.request, self.view, org))

    @patch_memberships
    def test_permissions_is_organization_owner_returns_false_when_membership_is_not_admin(self):
        org = MagicMock()
        self.create_membership(org, False)
        self.assertFalse(self.permission.has_object_permission(self.request, self.view, org))

    @patch_memberships
    def test_permissions_is_organization_owner_returns_true_when_membership_is_admin(self):
        org = MagicMock()
        self.create_membership(org, True)
        self.assertTrue(self.permission.has_object_permission(self.request, self.view, org))
```

I used a [library](https://github.com/stphivos/django-mock-queries) that I wrote that mocks django queryset functions to make the tests smaller and more readable. But if you prefer you can use `Mock` or `MagicMock` to patch only the things you need.

**EDIT**: For the sake of completeness let's assume you also wanted to integration test `OrganizationViewSet`, here's some tests for that:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from model_mommy import mommy


class TestOrganizationViewSet(TestCase):
    url = '/organizations/'

    def create_user(self, is_admin):
        password = 'password'

        user = mommy.prepare(User, is_admin=is_admin)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user, password

    def get_organizations_as(self, user=None, password=None):
        api = Client()

        if user:
            mommy.make(Membership, user=user, organization=mommy.make(Organization))
            api.login(username=user.username, password=password)

        return api.get(self.url)

    def test_organizations_viewset_returns_200_for_admins(self):
        response = self.get_organizations_as(*self.create_user(True))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_organizations_viewset_returns_403_for_non_admins(self):
        response = self.get_organizations_as(*self.create_user(False))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)

    def test_organizations_viewset_returns_403_for_anonymous(self):
        response = self.get_organizations_as()
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
```

As others have pointed out, you need those tests too, just not for every possible test case. Unit tests are best for that, as integration tests will write to the database etc. and will make your CI procedures slower - in case that sort of thing is relevant to you.

Comment: This looks like a very decent approach. I'll let you know if this solves my problem.

Comment: This does test that the permission itself is working; it is also useful to test the the permission is being applied correctly to the view by sending requests to the endpoint with django's test client to ensure a `403` is returned as expected.

Comment: True but the OP asked for a way to `unit test permissions`, not a way to integration test `OrganizationViewSet`. Nevertheless, I updated my answer to include tests for that too.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. However, I'd like to improve somewhere which is to creating membership with `MagicMock` on `create_membership` method is cause to could not using `Model.objects.filter` as aspected. Instead, need to use `django_mock_queries.MockModel` class.

Answer (score 10):

I was wrangling with this myself, and I think I found a simple solution that tests the behavior of the permissions check in isolation without having to mock everything out. Since this response is coming 4 years after the original answer, Django may have evolved considerably since then.

Testing a permission seems to be as easy as instantiating the permission and testing its `has_permission` method with contrived objects. For instance, I tested this out with the `IsAdminUser` permission, and the test passed:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import RequestFactory, TestCase
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser


class IsAdminUserTest(TestCase):
    def test_admin_user_returns_true(self):
        admin_user = User.objects.create(username='foo', is_staff=True)
        factory = RequestFactory()

        request = factory.delete('/')
        request.user = admin_user

        permission_check = IsAdminUser()

        permission = permission_check.has_permission(request, None)

        self.assertTrue(permission)
```

Changing `is_staff` to `False` in the User instantiation causes the test to fail as I'd expect.

**Updating this with an actual example**

I wrote my own custom permission to check if a user is an admin (staff user) and to allow only read-only operations otherwise. Note that, since this is a unit test, it doesn't interface with any endpoint or even seek to mock those out; it just tests the expected behavior of the permissions check.

Here's the permission:

```py
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsAdminUserOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return request.user.is_staff
```

And here's the full unit test suite:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import RequestFactory, TestCase
from community.permissions import IsAdminUserOrReadOnly


class IsAdminOrReadOnlyTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.admin_user = User.objects.create(username='foo', is_staff=True)
        self.non_admin_user = User.objects.create(username='bar')
        self.factory = RequestFactory()

    def test_admin_user_returns_true(self):
        request = self.factory.delete('/')
        request.user = self.admin_user

        permission_check = IsAdminUserOrReadOnly()

        permission = permission_check.has_permission(request, None)

        self.assertTrue(permission)

    def test_admin_user_returns_true_on_safe_method(self):
        request = self.factory.get('/')
        request.user = self.admin_user

        permission_check = IsAdminUserOrReadOnly()

        permission = permission_check.has_permission(request, None)

        self.assertTrue(permission)

    def test_non_admin_user_returns_false(self):
        request = self.factory.delete('/')
        request.user = self.non_admin_user

        permission_check = IsAdminUserOrReadOnly()

        permission = permission_check.has_permission(request, None)

        self.assertFalse(permission)

    def test_non_admin_user_returns_true_on_safe_method(self):
        request = self.factory.get('/')
        request.user = self.non_admin_user

        permission_check = IsAdminUserOrReadOnly()

        permission = permission_check.has_permission(request, None)

        self.assertTrue(permission)
```

I assume you could use a similar pattern for just about any user attribute you wanted to write a permission against.

When I get to integration/functional testing, only then will I worry about how this permission affects the interfaces of the API.

Comment: What is this stuff about RequestFactory.delete ?

Comment: @Itération122442 that's a `delete` request that a read-only user shouldn't have permission to perform.

Answer (score 1):

As a small enhancement/alternative for the approach outlined above, I would use pytest's `admin_user` fixture provided for django support:

https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#admin-user-an-admin-user-superuser

So a happy path test could look something like this:

```
    def test_returns_200_when_user_is_authenticated(self, 
         client, admin_user):
    client.force_login(admin_user)

    response = client.put('/my_url/pk/', data={'some data'},
        content_type='application/json'))

    assert response.status_code == 200
```

And you could also test the opposite scenario where the user is not logged in:

```
   def test_returns_403_when_user_is_not_authenticated(
        self, client):

    response = client.put('/my_url/pk/', data={'some data'},
        content_type='application/json'))

    assert response.status_code == 403
```